# Templated function and placement new constructor parameters

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management, placement-new

I have a couple of templated methods declared in my Memory Manager class:

```
template <class T>
inline T* AllocateObject() { return new (Allocate(sizeof(T))) T(); }
template <class T, class arg0>
inline T* AllocateObject(arg0 a0) { return new (Allocate(sizeof(T))) T(a0); }
template <class T, class arg0, class arg1>
inline T* AllocateObject(arg0 a0, arg1 a1) { return new (Allocate(sizeof(T))) T(a0,a1); }
template <class T, class arg0, class arg1, class arg2>
inline T* AllocateObject(arg0 a0, arg1 a1, arg2 a2) { return new (Allocate(sizeof(T))) T(a0,a1,a2); }
```

The idea is that the methods will allocate memory for and call constructor of whatever class given.

The problem is if you want to supply constructor arguments.. the only solution I have is above where you overload the function for each variation. I don't find it very viable.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

Variadic templates to the rescue:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
T * AllocateObject(Args &&... args)
{
    return ::new (Allocate(sizeof(T)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: isn't that only in C++ 11? maybe I should've added I target C++ 03 if possible :p